# Storing and working with 300 digit integers

Tags: c

```
int main()
{
    unsigned long long key = 21739827982173982173921739217392173217397213271832193721973291732917321732132173971317382173213782163872163872163872163872163826176728328621321487219372198371298775647326409817402198732198432974329479832749173821732198732173217392173721372193728193782193792173921732171;
}
```

Compiler says the number I want to assign is too large for the type selected. How can I store this and then perform operations?

Comment: Use a multiple precision library like `libmp` for example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

C does not have any built-in support for this.  You need a "bignum" library (also known as an "arbitrary precision arithmetic" or "multiple precision arithmetic" library).  [GNU MP](http://gmplib.org/) is well-documented and popular.

EDIT: I just noticed that your variable is named "key", and the number appears to be roughly 900 bits long.  Are you trying to implement [RSA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_%28algorithm%29)? If so you really should use a well-tested cryptographic library; there are dozens of subtle errors you can make in an RSA implementation which will damage your security.  Options there include [gcrypt](https://www.gnu.org/software/libgcrypt/), [NSS](https://www.mozilla.org/projects/security/pki/nss/), and [OpenSSL](https://openssl.org/).  If you can be license-compatible with libgcrypt, I strongly recommend using that, just because its API and documentation are so much better than those of the other two.

Comment: Brute-forcing RSA modulus in my case to demonstrate why bad keys are bad.

Comment: Ah.  That may in fact be easier with a generic bignum library than with a crypto library.

Answer (score 3):

You can get a arbitrary-precision integer library from here.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic#Arbitrary-precision_software

You can use the arbitrary precision library to deal with big numbers.

**OR**

You can use double - it has a range of about 300 digits, but only 53 bits of precision, because it's stored as two parts, an exponent and a mantissa. 53 bits gives you a number in the range of 15-18 digits precise

Answer (score 1):

You'll need a big-integer or arbitrary-precision math library in most if not all cases.  (C's integer types are rarely if ever that large; there might be specialty compilers where it happens, but they're not at all mainstream.  Even if you manage to find such a compiler, your code will not be portable.)

Check out [GMP](http://gmplib.org/).